# How to proxy context of each element founded through jQuery.find() inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#List").find ("li").click ($.proxy(function () {
        alert (this);
}, this));
```

this - is global context in this case. How to proxy context of each founded LI separately?
Let's say LI elements are selector, so

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
```

and then I need to bind a click for each LI in order to push li.text() or li.attr("data-whatever") to another function.

Does it possible through .find() or looping is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is smart enough to bind each member of a matched set separately. So, you can simply do:

```
$("#List").find("li").click(function () {
    alert(this);
    console.log('text::', $(this).text());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/S99AL/)**